# hazelcast distributed queue removal is not working

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to remove the queue from IQueue after processing the message. But it is not getting removed from queue. i have called the remove method as below,

```
class HazelcastSample implements ItemListener<testMessage>{

void replicateMessage(){
TestHazelcast.getInstance().getHazelcastInstance().getQueue("testQueue").put(testMessage);
}


public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<testMessage> event) {

testMessage sampleMessage = (testMessage) event.getItem();

IQueue<Object> sampleQueue= TestHazelcast.getInstance().getHazelcastInstance().getQueue("testQueue");

boolean removed = false;
removed = sampleQueue.remove(sampleMessage);
}
}

can you please help what is wrong? why remove method is not working?

Thank you,
chandra
```

Comment: Can you create a unit test that I can run as well. You code is a bit too hard to understand.

Comment: Can you post some logging. I also saw the other question you posted and my gut feeling is that the cluster is not formed correctly.